# (C Language) Only show filled entries in list

Tags: c

I hope this will be the last time I ask something here. Everything in my Food Ordering Algorithm is finished, but showing the list of filled orders shows every slot available (0 to 100), rather than just the entries filled out. Any way to fix that?

Case 3: Shows all orders made. (But I want just the entries that are filled out, not the empty ones.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define TAM 100

typedef struct order
{
    char nome[50];
    char endereco[150];
    char pedido[300];
    char valor[10];
};

int main() 
{
    struct order lista[TAM];
    int busca, acha, i, menu;
    i = 0;
    menu = 0;
    int codigo = 0;
    int c = 0;
    
    while(menu != 4)
    {
        system("cls");
        
        printf("====================\n");
        printf("Selecione uma opcao\n");
        printf("====================\n");
        printf("1 - Cadastrar pedido\n");
        printf("2 - Consultar pedido\n");
        printf("3 - Emitir relatorio\n");
        printf("4 - Sair\n");
        scanf("%d", &menu);
        fflush(stdin);
        
        switch(menu)
        {
            case 1:
                system("cls");
                
                
                printf("Digite seu nome: \n");
                scanf("%49[^\n]", lista[i].nome);
                fflush(stdin);
                
                printf("Digite seu endereco: \n");
                scanf("%149[^\n]", lista[i].endereco);
                fflush(stdin);
                
                printf("Digite seu pedido: \n");
                scanf("%299[^\n]", lista[i].pedido);
                fflush(stdin);
                
                printf("Digite o valor total: \n");
                scanf("%9[^\n]", lista[i].valor);
                fflush(stdin);
                
                system("cls");
                
                printf("Codigo: %d\n", codigo);
                printf("Nome: %s\n", lista[i].nome);
                printf("Endereco: %s\n", lista[i].endereco);
                printf("Pedido: %s\n", lista[i].pedido);
                printf("Valor total: %s\n", lista[i].valor);
                system("pause");
                
                i = i + 1;
                codigo = codigo + 1;
                
                break;
                
            case 2:
                
                system("cls");
            
            printf("Insira o codigo que deseja buscar:\n");
            scanf("%d", &busca);
            fflush(stdin);
            

                if(busca < codigo)
                {

                    printf("=============================\n");
                    printf("Codigo: %d\n", busca);
                    printf("Nome: %s\n", lista[busca].nome);
                    printf("Endereco: %s\n", lista[busca].endereco);
                    printf("Pedido: %s\n", lista[busca].pedido);
                    printf("Valor total: %s\n", lista[busca].valor);
                    printf("=============================\n");
                    system("pause");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("\n Codigo nao encontrado\n");
                    system("pause");
                    break;
                }
        
            break;
            
                
            case 3:
                system("cls");
                
                c = 0;
                
                for(i = 0; i < TAM; i++){
                    printf("=============================\n");
                    printf("Codigo: %d\n", c);
                    printf("Nome: %s\n", lista[i].nome);
                    printf("Endereco: %s\n", lista[i].endereco);
                    printf("Pedido: %s\n", lista[i].pedido);
                    printf("Valor total: %s\n", lista[i].valor);
                    printf("=============================\n");
                    
                    c = c + 1;
                }
                system("pause");
                break;
                
            case 4:
                return 0;
                
            default:
                printf("Opcao invalido\n");
                system("pause");
        }
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin);`?! Clearly whatever method you're using to learn C is not working, because that common error is not C. `fflush` is defined only for streams with which the last operation was _output_, and `stdin` is purely an input stream, so the behaviour is undefined. See also [this FAQ](https://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush2.html) and please tell us the name of the book you're using so we can suggest a better one.

Comment: Hint: you only need 1 call to `printf()` for any continuous block of output -- regardless of the number of lines.  Each of your blocks with multiple lines of output can be done with a single `printf()`. `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior -- except for the non-standard implementation by Microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
for(i = 0; i < TAM; i++){
```

to

```
for(i = 0; i < codigo ; i++){
```

codigo is the count og entrries, TAM is the max number of entries